# Get target of shortcut folder

Tags: c#, directory, target, shortcut

How do you get the directory target of a shortcut folder? I've search everywhere and only finds target of shortcut file.

Comment: this does not relates to wpf at all, I removed the tag

Comment: This is the solution I prefer: [How do i get the path name from a file shortcut ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13079688/3757210)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you will need to use COM and add a reference to "Microsoft Shell Control And Automation", as described in [this blog post](http://www.saunalahti.fi/janij/blog/2006-12.html#d6d9c7ee-82f9-4781-8594-152efecddae2):

Here's an example using the code provided there:

```
namespace Shortcut
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using Shell32;

    class Program
    {
        public static string GetShortcutTargetFile(string shortcutFilename)
        {
            string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFilename);
            string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(shortcutFilename);

            Shell shell = new Shell();
            Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
            FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
            if (folderItem != null)
            {
                Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
                return link.Path;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string path = @"C:\link to foobar.lnk";
            Console.WriteLine(GetShortcutTargetFile(path));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to find out how to look for a shortcuf folder programmaticaly :)

Comment: I work on Windows 7 64 bit, and it fails in finding shortcut to VirtualBox installed in `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBoxOSX`. It kept returning the target to be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\VirtualBoxOSX\VirtualBox.exe`. Any explanation on this behaviour?

Comment: Using Shell32 with this method only allow in single thread application. You have to include [STAThread] in main entry point. You will get exception in unit testing with this code because unit testing is not allow STAThread. see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543340/calling-shell32-dll-from-net-windows-service). There is also solution to run this code in unit testing see http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/20/xunit-and-sta/

Answer (score 7):

In windows 10 it needs to be done like this, first add COM reference to "Microsoft Shell Control And Automation"

```
// new way for windows 10
string targetname;
string pathOnly = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(LnkFileName);
string filenameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(LnkFileName);

Shell shell = new Shell();
Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(pathOnly);
FolderItem folderItem = folder.ParseName(filenameOnly);
if (folderItem != null) {
  Shell32.ShellLinkObject link = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;
  targetname = link.Target.Path;  // <-- main difference
  if (targetname.StartsWith("{")) { // it is prefixed with {54A35DE2-guid-for-program-files-x86-QZ32BP4}
    int endguid = targetname.IndexOf("}");
    if (endguid > 0) {
      targetname = "C:\\program files (x86)" + targetname.Substring(endguid + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Windows 10 is a piece of garbage.  This is probably why there are so many problems with links on Windows 10.

Comment: @EJThayer  Which Win 10 version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler way to get the linked path that I use is:

```
private static string LnkToFile(string fileLink)
{
    string link = File.ReadAllText(fileLink);
    int i1 = link.IndexOf("DATA\0");
    if (i1 < 0)
        return null;
    i1 += 5;
    int i2 = link.IndexOf("\0", i1);
    if (i2 < 0)
        return link.Substring(i1);
    else
        return link.Substring(i1, i2 - i1);
}
```

But it will of course break if the lnk-file format changes.

Comment: This only works for trivial `*.lnk` files - it won't work for `*.lnk` files created by Windows Installer (which don't point to files anyway) as well as certain other kinds of `*.lnk` files that don't store the path as a single string - unfortunately the binary file format is kinda complex: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-shllink/16cb4ca1-9339-4d0c-a68d-bf1d6cc0f943

Comment: Didn't work in my case, the function already return null on my .lnk files.

Comment: I think the .lnk format has changed, i can't find any "DATA" keyword inside the lnk file anymore. THe only valid solution is to use Shell.Application helper object, that is aware of all internal format details of these nasty lnk files.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetLnkTarget(string lnkPath)
{
    var shl = new Shell();
    var dir = shl.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath));
    var itm = dir.Items().Item(Path.GetFileName(lnkPath));
    var lnk = (ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;

    if (!File.Exists(lnk.Path)){
       return lnk.Path.Replace("Program Files (x86)", "Program Files");
    }
    else{
       return lnk.Path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this, always based on builtin windows "Shell.Application" COM object, but implemented using pure late-binding and reflection, thus without any need to add a reference to the existing project, and without any dependencies.

```
    public static string GetLnkTarget(string lnkPath)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(lnkPath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException();

        Type shlType;
        object shl = null;
        object dir = null;
        object items = null;
        object itm = null;
        object lnk = null;

        try
        {
            //var shl = new Shell();
            shlType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
            shl = Activator.CreateInstance(shlType);

            string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(lnkPath);
            string lnkFile = Path.GetFileName(lnkPath);

            //var dir = shl.NameSpace(dirName);
            dir = shlType.InvokeMember("NameSpace", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, shl, new object[] { dirName });

            //var itm = dir.Items().Item(lnkFile);
            items = dir.GetType().InvokeMember("Items", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, dir, null);
            itm = items.GetType().InvokeMember("Item", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, items, new object[] { lnkFile });

            //var lnk = (ShellLinkObject)itm.GetLink;
            lnk = itm.GetType().InvokeMember("GetLink", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, itm, null);

            //return lnk.Path;
            object path = lnk.GetType().InvokeMember("Path", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, lnk, null);
            return (string)path;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lnk != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(lnk);
            if (itm != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itm);
            if (items != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items);
            if (dir != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(dir);
            if (shl != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(shl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

if you want find your application path that has shortcut on desktop, an easy way that i use, is the following:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Substring(0, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\")
```

this code return any exe path that is running,Regardless that who requested file

Comment: This does not answer the question as such.

Answer (score -4):

All file shortcuts have a .lnk file extension you can check for. Using a string for example, you could use string.EndsWith(".lnk") as a filter.

All URL shortcuts have a .url file extension, so you will need to account for those as well if needed.

Comment: OP asked how to get the target directory of the shortcut, not how to check if it is a shortcut.