# How to follow a shortcut in powershell

Tags: powershell, symlink, shortcut, cd

In powershell, you use `cd dir` to go into the directory `dir`.

But if `dir` is a shortcut to a directory, `cd dir` and `cd dir.lnk` both give an error, saying that the directory doesn't exist.

So how do I follow that shortcut?

(In Linux `cd dir` *just works*. In Windows, I've got no idea)

Comment: Windows shortcut is actually [a binary file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) that needs explicit parsing or [COM access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9414152). NTFS supports symbolic links too (like the Ext fs in Linux), but those are seldom used.

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728510/how-to-follow-a-symbolic-soft-link-in-cmd-or-powershell

Answer (score 5):

Using the shell com-object, you can get the target path and from there, do what you wish.  `Get-ShortcutTargetPath`

```
function Get-ShortcutTargetPath($fileName) {
    $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    $targetPath = $sh.CreateShortcut($fileName).TargetPath 
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sh) | Out-Null
    return $targetPath
}


$file = 'Path\to\Filename.lnk'
$TargetPath = Get-shortcutTargetPath($file)

if (Test-Path -PathType Leaf $TargetPath) {
    $TargetPath = Split-Path -Path $TargetPath
}

Set-Location $TargetPath
```

Comment: The `$TargetPath` contains the executable name which cannot be used with `Set-Location`. Perhaps `Set-Location $(Split-Path -Path $TargetPath)`

Comment: @lit Indeed. I edited my code to include a `Split-Path` based on your comment. If the target is a container though, it is important to not perform the Split-Path, otherwise you'll get the parent container of the target container.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't actually work for me, the first does nothing and the second gives me the error **"The shortcut pathname must end with .lnk or .url."**

However, after digging through MSDN for a while I worked out a solution. I have no idea why I can't find any answers to this on Google, but I even travelled to the untouched second and third pages and tried multiple keywords... I guess the search results are just buried for some reason. But here's how I solved the problem. Using a while loop and the Get-Item command, you can follow a symbolic link to it's true path! Works for directory links, too.

So far the double-cd approach is the most reliable/universal I can find for handling a situation of mixed relative/absolute paths in the filenames and targets, and I tested several scenarios.

```
function getLinkTarget($fn) {
    $op=$PWD #Save original path
    while($t=(Get-Item $fn).Target) { #Get link target
        cd (Split-Path -Parent $fn) #cd to parent of file/dir
        cd (Split-Path -Parent $t) #cd again to parent of target
        $fn=(Split-Path -Leaf $t) #Set filename to relative target
    }
    $fn=(Join-Path $PWD $fn) #Make path absolute
    cd $op #Change back to original path
    return $fn
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 10  cd directory_name or cd dir*  if you only want part of the name assuming no other directories start with the same dir*.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. `cd : Cannot find path 'src*' because it does not exist.`