# How to follow a symbolic/soft link in cmd or PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, symlink, shortcut-file

My searches have only shown me how to create symbolic links using **mklink** in cmd. I have seen some things saying to use **readlink**, but PowerShell and cmd don't know what **readlink** is, and **cd** obviously doesn't work. So how do I follow one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your question i made this batch file:

```
mkdir truedir
dir > truedir\fileone.txt
mklink /d symdir truedir
cd symdir
dir
```

And i have found no problem to get the content of the symblic link to a directory from command prompt.
No problem also with powershell 5.1 (win 10):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\<user>\OneDrive\Desktop\test2\symdir
```

Can you give us a code example (batch or powershell is the same) to replicate your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought .lnk files were symbolic links, but I realize that is not the case now. Do you know how to follow a .lnk? If not I can just create actual symbolic links instead.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276418/how-to-follow-a-shortcut-in-powershell

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Now that I have my terms straightened out, I should able to do this now.

Answer (score 19):

To avoid confusion stemming from your question:

- Windows **[*shortcut files* (`*.lnk` files)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing))**, which are a **feature of the [Windows (GUI) *shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell)**, are distinct from **[*symbolic links* (*symlinks*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)**, which are a **feature of the (NTFS) *filesystem***.
- **Shortcut files** - which you are interested in - store the path of a file or folder they point to *inside the file*, which is why:

  - You **cannot directly `cd` to a shortcut file's target folder**, because filesystem commands such as `cd` know nothing about the *content* of files.
  - You **must read the *content* of the shortcut file to determine its target**, which you can then pass to `cd` or `Set-Location` (in PowerShell).
  - The file format of shortcut file is a binary one that can be read via an [in-box COM component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/aew9yb99%28v%3dvs.84%29) that exposes Windows shell functionality; e.g., to determine the target folder of a shortcut file named `Samples.lnk` and change to that folder, use PowerShell:

    ```
    # NOTE: * Despite the name "CreateShortcut()", the method is also
    #         used to *read* shortcut files.
    #       * Prefixing the filename with "$PWD/" is needed in order
    #         to target a file in the current directory, because
    #         the method doesn't know what PowerShell's current dir. is.
    cd (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut("$PWD/Samples.lnk").TargetPath
    ```
- **Symlinks**, by contrast:

  - **(typically) transparently *redirect* to their *target***, i.e., the filesystem item (file or folder) they point to.
  - You can therefore **use `cd` directly with a symlink to a folder**, but note that it is still the *symlink*'s path that is shown.
  - To ***print* a symlink's target** - akin to what the `readlink` utility does on *Unix-like platforms* - use PowerShell; e.g., to print the target of a symlink named `Samples` in the current directory:

    ```
     (Get-Item Samples).Target

     # Or, after running `cd Samples`:
     (Get-Item .).Target
    ```
  - Note that it's not straightforward to get a symlink's target in `cmd.exe`, but if you use 
    `dir /al <link-path>*`, the listing will also show the link's target path, after the name, enclosed in `[...]`; note that the trailing `*` is necessary in order to show information about the link itself, not its target's *contents*; note that, although unlikely, that may match other links that start with the same path as well.

---

Unlike shortcut files, **symlinks are still rare in the Windows world**, not least because prior to Windows 10 they *invariably* required admin privileges to create; in Windows 10, if developer mode is enabled (by an administrator), even non-administrative users / non-elevated processes can now create symlinks - see https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/, which also explains why symlinks are **likely to see increasing usage in the future**.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Do you know how I can create hard links? Even using an elevated cmd, I can't create them. I believe this is because Windows sets all folders to be read-only by default. Unchecking the read-only box only applies to files within the folder.

Comment: @Deoxal: Hardlinks can only target _files_, so you need to either use _symlinks_ (symbolic links) or _junctions_ if you want to target _folders_. I suggest using symlinks, which provide the most flexibility (they can also target folders on other volumes / machines).

Comment: I wonder how to follow hard links.  Windows apps seem to use them often, like windows terminal, $env:localappdata\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe.  fsutil seems to spit out binary.

Comment: @js2010, you can't really _follow_ hardlinks, but you can see all other paths that link to the same data. In Windows PowerShell only, you can inspect the `.Target` property of what `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` returns (this was removed from PowerShell Core).

Comment: I guess the reparsepoints windows apps make are an exception.  There's no target property with those.  I posted a question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697488/follow-hard-links-reparsepoints-to-files-windows-terminal

Answer (score 1):

Okay I just posted this answer in another similar question so I figured I'd post it here too. I wish this one had come up in a search like the other question did because @mklement0's answer is great. But here is my solution that is able to follow nested links to the true file or directory in PowerShell (I was looking for a PS-specific solution, not CMD).

So far the double-cd approach is the most reliable/universal I can find for handling a situation of mixed relative/absolute paths in the filenames and targets, and I tested several scenarios.

```
function getLinkTarget($fn) {
    $op=$PWD #Save original path
    while($t=(Get-Item $fn).Target) { #Get link target
        cd (Split-Path -Parent $fn) #cd to parent of file/dir
        cd (Split-Path -Parent $t) #cd again to parent of target
        $fn=(Split-Path -Leaf $t) #Set filename to relative target
    }
    $fn=(Join-Path $PWD $fn) #Make path absolute
    cd $op #Change back to original path
    return $fn
}
```