# How to use PowerShell to create a SymbolicLink for an exe with a file path parameter?

Tags: powershell, symlink, new-item

I am trying to create a Windows desktop shortcut (SymbolicLink) that runs a PowerShell script.  If this were executed from the command line, it would be:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit -file "C:\User\BFT\Test\HelloWorld.ps1"
```

And the command line does work with this.

I can also create a shortcut by right-clicking on the desktop, selecting New, selecting shortcut, and loading the above command into the dialog.  This also works just fine.

When I attempt to create this shortcut in PowerShell using the command:

```
New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "c:\User\BFT\Test" -Name "Test" -Target """C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noexit -file "C:\User\BFT\Test\HelloWorld.ps1"""
```

I receive an error saying

> New-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'noexit'.

I have tried several versions involving different quoting, with and without -noexit and -file, etc.  None seem to work.

It would appear PowerShell can't deal with both the exe and the file path portion, but this seems like it should be a common use and I would think there is a way.  I am probably missing something.

Any help in suggesting solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Shortcut files* (`.lnk` files) aren't the same as *symbolic links*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732814/45375) for background information.

**`New-Item` doesn't support creating shortcut files**, only symbolic links,

**To create shortcut files programmatically, you must use the `WScript.Shell` COM component**, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743337/45375).