# unexpected behavior when creating a path with %userProfile% environment variable in pwershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, shortcut-file, mklink, new-item

I've written a script to create a series of symbolic links. I want to set the target value to $shortpath where

```
$shortpath = "%userprofile%\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext"
```

The value of the $shortpath variable is valid and I can open it from the run command. The string that PS is trying to write at the creation of the symlink is different than anticipated. I expect that it would write the value of the string, or at least insert the value of the Env Variable. rather it is adding to the string I pass to it.

```
New-Item -Path $currpath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value ($targetpath) -Force
```

I would expect a target value to be: c:\Users\UserName\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext or %userprofile%\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext

Instead, I am getting: C:\windows\system32%UserProfile$\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext

example of output written to logfile:

```
wholepath = C:\Users\UserName\dir1\dir2\dir3\longfilename1.ext
spath = C:\Users\UserName\dir1\dir2\dir3\longfi~1.ext
envpath = C:\Users\UserName\
midpart = dir1\dir2\dir3\
filename = longfi~1.ext
targetpath = %UserProfile%\dir1\dir2\dir3\longfi~1.ext
```

Could anyone shed some light as to why this may be happening?  The same thing is happening if i user mklink.  I've added the entire script below:

---

```
function Get-ShortPathName
{
    Param([string] $path)

    $MethodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "GetShortPathNameW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetShortPathName(string pathName, System.Text.StringBuilder shortName, int cbShortName);
'@

    $Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru
    $shortPath = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder(500)
    $retVal = $Kernel32::GetShortPathName($path, $shortPath, $shortPath.Capacity)
    return $shortPath.ToString()

    }

    $logfile="C:\SwSetup\SymLinkScript\log.txt"
    
    <#paths to orignials and place to copy to#>
    $src = $env:userprofile + "\Firestone Technical Resources, Inc\Firestone Technical Resources, Inc Team Site - Documents\Danielle"
    $dest = "C:\SwSetup\asdfg\"
    $src = $src.Replace("\","\\")


    <#  grab the root object, and its children, from the src#>
    $i = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $src -Recurse

    <# recurse through the root and process, for lack of a better term, each object#>
    $i | ForEach-Object { 
        Process {
            $apath = $_.FullName -Replace $src,""
            $cpath = $dest + $apath

            <# Create Directory if it does not exist#>
            If(!(Test-Path (Split-Path -Parent $cpath))){
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path (Split-Path -Parent $cpath)
            }
            
            <#
            Create the SymLink if it does not exist
            mklink syntax         | PowerShell equivalent       
            mklink /D Link Target | new-item -path <path to location> -itemtype symboliclink -name <the name> -value <path to target>
            #>
            If(!$_.PSIsContainer){
                If(!(Get-Item $cpath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
                    <#establish 8.3path#>
                    $wholepath = ([WildcardPattern]::Escape($_.FullName))
                    $shortPath = Get-ShortPathName($wholepath)
                    $envpath = $shortpath.substring(0,18)
                    $midpart = ((Split-path $shortpath -parent).trimstart($envpath)) +"\"
                    $filename = Split-Path $shortpath -leaf
                    $targetpath = "%UserProfile%\" + $midpart + $filename
                    
                    <#write to log file#>
                    "wholepath = " + $wholepath >> $logfile
                    "spath = " + $Shortpath >>$logfile
                    "envpath = " + $envpath >> $logfile
                    "midpart = " +$midpart >>$logfile
                    "filename = " + $filename >> $logfile
                    "targetpath = " + $targetpath >> $logfile
                    "cpath = " + [string]$cpath >> $logfile
                    "----------" >>$logfile
                    " " >>$logfile
                    
                    <#create symlink#>
                    New-Item -Path $cpath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value ($targetpath) -Force

                    <#cmd /c mklink $cpath $targetpath#>

                    <#create shortcut
                    $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
                    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($targetpath.substring(0,$targetpath.Length-4) + '.lnk')
                    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $targetpath
                    $Shortcut.Save()#>
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ***Shortcut files* (`.lnk`)** *do* support `cmd.exe`-style environment variable references (e.g. `%USERPROFILE%`) in their properties, but there's a **caveat**:

  - When a shortcut file is created or modified with WshShell COM object's [`.CreateShortcut()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//xsy6k3ys(v=vs.85)) *API*:

    - *Assigning* property values, say, `.TargetPath = '%USERPROFILE%\Desktop'` works as expected - that is, the string is stored as-is and the reference to environment variable `%USERPROFILE%` is only expanded *at runtime*, i.e. when the shortcut file is *opened*.
    - However, *querying* such properties via this COM API *also* performs expansion, so that you won't be able to get *raw* definitions, and won't be able to distinguish between the `.TargetPath` property containing `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` and, say, *verbatim* `C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop`
  - When in doubt about a given `.lnk` file's actual property values, inspect it via *File Explorer*.
- ***Symbolic links*** (symlinks) do *not*.

**The target of a symbolic link must be specified as a *literal* path**, which in your case means using [*PowerShell's* environment-variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) (e.g., `$env:UserProfile`) in order to resolve the variable reference to its value *up front*:

```
# This results in a *literal* path, because $env:UserProfile is
# instantly resolved; the result can be used with New-Item / mklink
$literalTargetPath = "$env:UserProfile\" + $midpart + $filename
```

Passing something like `'%USERPROFILE%\Desktop'` to the `-Value` / `-Target` parameter of `New-Item -Type SymbolicLink` therefore does *not* work (as intended), but the symptom depends on which PowerShell edition you're running:

- *Windows PowerShell*, which you're using, tries to verify the existence of the target path up front, and therefore *fails to create the symlink*, because it interprets `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` *verbatim*, as a *relative* path (relative to the current directory, which is why the latter's path is prepended), which doesn't exist.
- *PowerShell (Core) 7+* also interprets the path *verbatim*, but it allows creating symlinks with *not-yet-existing* targets, so the symlink creation itself succeeds. However, trying to *use* the resulting symlink then fails, because its target doesn't exist.

Comment: I am able to, using explorer, bring up the properties of a symbolic link and change its target to use the %userprofile% environment variable.  I can't however seem to find a way to do this programatticaly.

Comment: @Mlesko, you cannot modify the properties of a _symlink_ in File Explorer, only those of a _shortcut file_ - and only the latter support environment-variable references, as noted in the answer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732814/45375) for a discussion of their differences.

Answer (score 0):

First you have set a variable called `$shortpath`:

> $shortpath = "%userprofile%\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext"

and then you say:

> New-Item -Path $currpath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value ($targetpath)
> -Force
>
> I would expect a target value to be:
> c:\Users\UserName\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext or
> %userprofile%\dir1\dir2\dir3\filename.ext

The reason your expectation is not met is that your `New-Item` line doesn't refer to your `$shortpath` variable.

Comment: $shortpath is the 8.3 style of the filepath.  it is used to create the $targetpath that is given to the new-item call.  at time of execution the new-item call parses the %userprofile% env variable.  My desired outcome is for the target of the symlink to be the string "%userprofile%\dir1\dir2\filename.ext" rather than "c:\users\USERNAME\dir1\dir2\filename.ext"  when passed the literal string it is prepending the path the script is run from to it.  EG c:\windows\sys32\%userProfile%\dir1\etc.

Comment: The variable-name confusion is unfortunate, but the real problem is that symbolic links do not support `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references in their target paths - they only support _literal_ paths.