# How can I find the target filename of an executable shortcut?

Tags: c#, .net, shortcut-file

I have an application Test.exe in C:/Program Files/Test folder. I need to place a shortcut of Test.exe in a folder on desktop with name TestShortcut.lnk. If a user run the application via shortcut, how would I programmatically get the the path and filename of the TestShortcut.lnk instead of the actual Test.exe in C#.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414152/get-target-of-shortcut-folder) SO post be of any use to you?

Comment: I tried the everything that's in the link, could get that to work. All i'm getting is path to original executable.

Comment: You can't know if an process got started from a short cut or anywhere else for that matter, unless you use some convention, for example, have the shortcut add an argument to the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get target of shortcut folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414152/get-target-of-shortcut-folder)

Comment: yes, i was able to get the file path of executable with rene's comment