# Cannot access file in Windows Shortcut from .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .NET application which checks if a file exists in a Windows Shortcut. But the File.Exists method return false.

```
var filePath= @"E:\Reports\abc.pdf" //Where Reports is a windows shortcut to a Azure File Share
var isExists = File.Exists(filePath)
Console.WriteLine(isExists) //prints false
```

What did I try?

- I verified that the account under which the program runs has access to shortcut and azure fileshare

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You get false because this folder does not exist. What exists is a link file:

> E:\Reports.lnk

So if you want to access the location first you need to [determine the target of that shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414152/get-target-of-shortcut-folder).